# Parallel.ForEach Loop with Thread-Local boolean

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety, parallel.foreach

I've read Microsoft's guidelines for running a [Parallel.ForEach loop with thread-local variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997393(v=vs.110).aspx) which makes sense for counters and/or updating objects. My question though is the need for it when dealing with a local boolean variable.
Consider the following code (it's just a sample, the actual code does a whole lot more):

```
public bool ParallelForEachLoopWithThreadLocalBoolVariable(IEnumerable<string> items)
{
    bool doWork = false;
    Parallel.ForEach<string, bool>(items,
                                   () => false,
                                   (match, loop, madeChange) =>
                                   {
                                        if (match == "valid")
                                        {
                                            madeChange = true;
                                            ProcessMatch(match);
                                        }   
                                        return madeChange;
                                   },
                                   (changed) => doWork = changed
                                   );
    return doWork;
}

public bool ParallelForEachLoop(IEnumerable<string> items)
{
    bool doWork = false;
    Parallel.ForEach(items, match =>
                     {
                        if (match == "valid")
                        {
                            doWork = true;
                            ProcessMatch(match);
                        }   
                    });
    return doWork;
}
```

My ultimate goal is to spread the work done in the `ProcessMatch()` method and return a flag indicating if the overall work has made any difference.
I tend to go with the `ParallelForEachLoop` method as I believe that `ParallelForEachLoopWithThreadLocalBoolVariable` will assign the boolean value to each partition and might end up with a wrong interpretation if the last partition to do the work ends as false (i.e. match != "valid").
I just fear that the local variable, `doWork`, might throw an exception if it's accessed by multiple threads in the `ParallelForEachLoop` method. I really just need to set the doWork once if the condition is met, even if it only happens once throughout the entire iteration loop (I definitely need to run the `ProcessMatch` on each valid match though).
Are my fears justified? Can I use the `ParallelForEachLoop` function without any fears it might not work in some scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, assigning a valid value to a variable (note, a variable **NOT** a property) you will never get a exception thrown<sup>1</sup>, so your concern for the 2nd method is not valid.

Thread local variables are so you can perform non-atomic operations (operations that could have something else happen "during" it, changing the outcome) without having to lock on a resource, you then can perform another operation less frequently (in the final block) and do lock on that operation and aggregate your results. However assigning a value to a `bool` is an atomic operation so there is no need to use a local variable. In the MSDN example you linked to they do `+=` on a integer which is not atomic and would either need to be locked on or use a local variable like they do in the example to make sure that another thread did not modify the value to the left of the `+=` before the new result was assigned.

In short, use your 2nd version.

---

<sup>1: Assigning a value to a variable is one of the few things you are allowed to do in a [Constrained Execution Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228973(v=vs.110).aspx)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I guess "...assigning a value to a bool is an atomic operation" is what I was looking for (along with the affirmation that assigning (a valid) value to variable doesn't throw an exception). Thanks again!

Comment: Most built in value types have atomic assignment, the only one I know of that is not is a `long` running on a 32 bit platform. however you can use [`Interlocked.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.read(v=vs.110).aspx) and the other `interlocked` functions on that to give you atomicity.